# Font-size: Deixar uma fonte 100% do tamanho da DIV

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou criando banners para impressão e me deparei com um problema.

Preciso definir uma div de height e widht fixos, por exemplo:

```
#papel {width: 297mm;height: 210mm;border:1px solid red}
```

Dentro desta div, tenho um SPAN

```
#papel span{font-size: 9vw;border:1px solid red;font-family:Arial;}
```

O problema, é o seguinte: O meu texto cabe dentro da DIV, porém o elemento geram uma borda em volta do meu texto, saindo da DIV.

Há uma forma do meu Span ocupar 100% da DIV ?  Gostaria que o texto ocupasse todo espaço da DIV sem ultrapassa-la com a borda.

Segue codigo siples para demonstração:

```css
#papel {width: 150mm;height: 30mm;border:1px solid red;}

#papel span{font-size: 19vw;border:1px solid green;font-family:Arial;}
```

```html
<div id="papel">
 <span>RES</span>
</div>
```

Agradeço desde já =D

Comment: Você definiu a div de um tamanho em que o texto não cabe.

Comment: Extamante... note que o texto "cabe" na DIV, o problema é a borda que um elemento gera... Preciso que o texto ocupe o maximo de espaço em minha DIV.

Comment: Não é só diminuir o tamanho da fonte? =/

Comment: Não, ele não cabe. Só você usar um acento ou um "gjy" que vai entender.

Comment: Entendo... há uma forma de remover essas bordas? Msm cortando acentos rs

Comment: Sim. Primeiro zerando padding e margin, e depois definindo a div com a mesma altura da linha, ou nem definindo nada, deixando ela se adaptar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Antes de mais nada

Sua premissa está incorreta, seu texto não cabe na `div`. Sua escolha de letras pode ter dado esta ilusão, veja um exemplo melhor:

```css
#papel {width: 150mm;height: 30mm;border:1px solid red}

#papel span{font-size: 19vw;border:1px solid green;font-family:Arial;}
```

```html
<div id="papel">
 <span>ÇÃj</span>
</div>
```

### Mudando o comportamento do `span` e da `div`

Uma alternativa é deixar a div do tamanho da linha (ou a linha do tamanho da div), de forma a ficarem iguais.

Além disso, se quer um controle maior, melhor tratar o `span` como bloco.

```css
#papel {width: 150mm;border:1px solid red}

#papel span{display:block;font-size: 19vw;border:1px solid green;font-family:Arial;}
```

```html
<div id="papel">
 <span>RES ÇÃj</span>
</div>
```

### Definindo altura com `line-height`

Se quiser ignorar os acentos e as letras que passam da *baseline*, conforme deixado no comentário, pode acertar o tamanho da linha da div:

```css
#papel {width: 150mm;height:30mm;border:1px solid red;overflow:hidden}

#papel span{font-size: 19vw;border:1px solid green;font-family:Arial;line-height:30mm}
```

```html
<div id="papel">
 <span>RES ÇÃj</span>
</div>
```

Se, no exemplo acima não quiser cortar os acentos totalmente, tire o `overflow:hidden`.

```css
#papel {width: 150mm;height:30mm;border:1px solid red}

#papel span{font-size: 19vw;border:1px solid green;font-family:Arial;line-height:30mm}
```

```html
<div id="papel">
 <span>RES ÇÃj</span>
</div>
```

Note que o que está valendo nestes últimos dois exemplos é exatamente o `line-height`, fazendo com que a fonte se alinhe para o espaço que tem, assim, o que "vazar" (ou o que for cortado) não vai interferir nos espaços dos elementos vizinhos.

> **Nota:** Eu acho que o mais fácil mesmo seria simplesmente especificar a altura da fonte em milímetros mesmo, não sei se faz algum sentido usar `vw` pra medidas em papel.

Comment: É verdade que `vw` não é muito útil para fonte. Mas se for necessário um tamanho relativo, uma unidade bastante comum é `em`

Comment: Eu ia responder justamente sobre isso na outra pergunta, nem imaginava que você tinha até desenhado, principalmente o ç,j,q,g, etc, parabéns e obrigado pelo empenho! +1

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso é só você definir a altura para 100% e trocar o span por uma div

```css
#papel {width: 150mm;height: 30mm;border:1px solid red;}

#papel div{font-size: 16vw;border:1px solid green;font-family:Arial; height: 100% }
```

```html
<div id="papel">
 <div>RES</div>
</div>
```